# Placing variables in php update query

Tags: php

Ok I know this is a simple question, I've been trying for hours now though.

I have four variables:

```
$id
$name
$part
$source
```

I am trying to place them into a query for updating my database like so:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET name='".$name."', part='".$part."' WHERE id='1'");
```

For some reason the WHERE isn't highlighted in red for my code editor like it should be (like UPDATE and SET are.)

How can I place these variables into the string without ending the string early?

I know it's an easy fix I just can't figure it out :(

Based on comments, I now have:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET name=".$name.", part=".$part." WHERE id=".$id."");
```

Comment: Isn't it an int that *shouldn't* be treated as a variable? So, these `' '` go out. BTW, did you try your query or are you basing your assumptions in the editor? If the latter, test your query to see if it brings the correct solution first.

Comment: That is true, but it still isn't right, I don't believe. And I did check it to see if it would work and it did not update the row in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this way:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE members SET name='$name', part='$part' WHERE id='1'");
```

You don't need to place this dots to connect variables to a mysql query, only the $ before the word is sufficient.

Comment: The connecting is called [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). `+1` anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate the values. Do it this way

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET name='$name', part='$part' WHERE id='1'");
```

I am assuming you have escaped those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Very popular question on a php developer interviewing, by the way: what is the difference between strings '' and "". First one is faster, because they are not parsed to find a variables, nut in "" you can put variables and interpreter will change their name to value.

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET name='$name', part='$part' WHERE id='$id'");
```

That way should work fir you AND highlight WHERE word, as you want it to. The string is in "", so variables will be changed to their values. Try this and tell us, is it ok or not.